# Negate decimal number regex pattern in order to strip it with replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace all characters, that do not match given regex pattern. While it's working for match, I can't seem to make multi-part regex patterns work with negations.

`[^\d.-]` works fine, in aspect of removing all non numeric and .- characters, but it still isn't good enough for decimal number, so I made the following pattern:

```
^[0-9]+(.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

However, I do not know how to negate this to get it to work in .replace. Any ideas? I assume the same will apply to all other patterns, for example : `^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$`

Thanks!

Example inputs that are valid for decimal:

```
1.1
1.00
1.23
23123981239.2
2
-1
```

Example replaces:

```
1.a4 => 1.4
44.44.4 => 44.444
qweqwe55.3 => 55.3
```

Comment: Can you add to the question what you want to match and what should not match?

Comment: Added example valid inputs. It should just be any integer number followed by optional decimal and then again any integer number (as in ^[0-9]+(.[0-9]{1,2})?$, but disregard the 2 decimal places)

Comment: Updated it once again @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Oh, as for with what, I would like to replace invalid characters with nothing, just ""

Comment: Maybe `.replace(/[^\d.-]+|(\..+?)\./, '$1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a split/join. The delimiter will be the pattern: `^.*?(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|\D+`.

The first part of the alternation reach the first number (that can be a single digit). Since I putted the number description in a capturing group, when this part is successful, only the capture content is returned.
Note that if the string contains at least one digit, you are sure that the first part will be the first successful match (since it is in first in the alternation). The `^` anchor prevents it to be successful later.

The second part match all non-digits.

Then you only have to join the result with an empty string.

```js
let strings = [
  "1.a4",
  "44.44.4",
  "qweqwe55.3",
  "44.44.4.4.3333.5",
  "-44.44.4.4.3333.5",
  "-44.44.4.4.3333.5-",
  "1.1",
  "1.00",
  "1.23",
  "23123981239.2",
  "2",
  "-1",
].map(str => str.split(/^.*?(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|\D+/).join('') );

console.log(strings)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one option might be to use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and make use of the callback function.

First replace all non dots, digits and hyphens `/[^\d.-]` with an empty string.

Then match an optional hyphen, 1+ digits and a dot in group 1. In group 2 match 0+ times any character except a newline.

```
(-?\d+\.)(.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i20F7G/1)

In the callback return the concatenation of group 1 and 2 where in group 2 all the non digits are replaced with an empty string.

```js
let strings = [
  "1.a4",
  "44.44.4",
  "qweqwe55.3",
  "44.44.4.4.3333.5",
  "-44.44.4.4.3333.5",
  "-44.44.4.4.3333.5-",
  "1.1",
  "1.00",
  "1.23",
  "23123981239.2",
  "2",
  "-1",
].map(str => {
  return str
    .replace(/[^\d.-]+/, '')
    .replace(/(-?\d+\.)(.*)/, function(m, g1, g2) {
      return g1 + g2.replace(/\D+/g, '');
    });
});

console.log(strings)
```

Comment: I suppose that would be a valid option, I just wanted to make it so that I can reuse pure patterns, instead of functions

Comment: @alps But you have to get the digits only from `1.a4` and remove the extra dots from `44.44.4` so you capture what you want and then do the replacement.